# Serializing string which has web url to JSon using DataContractJsonSerializer adding backslashes

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I am using `DataContractJsonSerializer` to serialize my C# class which has a property that stores web url

```
public class Info
{
 string Url{get; set;}
}
```

Storing to disk using the following code

```
FileStream stream = new FileStream("e:\\config.json", FileMode.Create);

var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
serializer.WriteObject(stream, obj);

stream.Close();
```

Add the following url to object

```
Info.Url = "https://google.com"
```

and serializing it I get the following json

```
"Info": { "Url" : "https:\/\/google.com" }
```

How can I avoid the escape character `\`

Comment: That escape character is explicitly required by the [JSON standard](http://json.org/): `char 
    any-Unicode-character-
        except-"-or-\-or-
        control-character
    \"
    \\
    \/
    \b
    \f
    \n
    \r
    \t
    \u four-hex-digits `

Comment: @dbc is there any way I can remove it?

Comment: Not with `DataContractJsonSerializer` since it is designed to write well-formed JSON.  You might be able to create invalid JSON like that using Json.NET if you serialize to a `JObject` then replace the `"Url"` property value with a [`JRaw`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JRaw.htm) - but I'm not sure.  Otherwise you'll need to do some manual string parsing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no problem the backslash in the json file.

You can visualize you json content through this site. You will see that the backslash doesn't appear in the visualization

http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/

As @dbc mentioned, is part of the DataContractJsonSerializer.